# Datafiles in /data/db are larger than the data set inserted in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I was wondering that for a given set of data, the MongoDB datafiles in /data/db are larger than the data set inserted into the database .Why such happening in mongoDB ? can someone clear me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB [preallocates disk space](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-DatafilePreallocation), so the actual storage on disk will always be larger than the data set.

> Each datafile is preallocated to a particular size.  (This is done to prevent file system fragmentation, among other reasons.)  The first filename for a database is .0, then .1, etc.  .0 will be 64MB, .1 128MB, et cetera, up to 2GB.  Once the files reach 2GB in size, each successive file is also 2GB.

Comment: I am concern about my server machine ,it deals with gazillion data , now its getting poor performance although it has good configuration.Any suggestion on this regard ? Thanks.

Comment: The preallocation should be helpful for performance on large data sets.  If you have poor performance, you're best posting a separate question with more specific details.  For example, is the problem related to inserting, updating, querying .. are you doing so via the DB shell or an application [driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers), etc.

Comment: For completeness, I will mention there are some [command line options](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters) such as `--noprealloc` and `--smallfiles` that can reduce the disk space usage.  These are should only be used for development/testing environments where space is limited and *not* for production environments.  See the [Excessive Disk Space](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space) wiki page for more info.